# Show result of matrix operation in terms of user defined matrices

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, replacement, group-theory

I have defined some matrices `K[0]`,`K[1]`,...,`K[9]` and `S[1]`,...,`S[5]`. I am trying to show that

$$K^aS^I-S^IK^a=2if^{aIJ}S^J$$

My question is how do I get the output of this expression to be displayed in terms of the $S$ matrices rather than the explicit matrix output.

There are 15 matrices (generators of $\small\mathrm{SU}(4)$ for context) I won't show them all but here is an example:

- `K[0] = KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[3], PauliMatrix[0]]`
- `S[4] = -KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[2]]`
- `S[5] = -KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2]]`

One operation I am doing is `K[0].S[4]-S[4].K[0]` I get the output `{{0,0,0,2},{0,0,-2,0},{0,2,0,0},{-2,0,0,0}}`. I want the output to be written as `2i.S[5]` instead.

Comment: Please post the matrices so that anyone can experiment with them. Welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Answer (score 2):

These matrices have the nice property that they are all orthogonal in the sense of `Tr[S[i].S[j]] = 4*KroneckerDelta[i,j]`. This means that you can get the coefficients with

```
coefflist[M_] := Table[Tr[M.S[i]], {i,15}]/4
```

You may need the 16th matrix though for completeness, the one that is equal to `IdentityMatrix[4]`. I'd rather suggest you go with a list of all 16 `S`-matrices like

```
Slist = KroneckerProduct @@@ Tuples[Array[PauliMatrix, 4], 2];
```

and then compute the decomposition of any $4\times4$ matrix with

```
coefflist[M_?MatrixQ /; Dimensions[M] == {4, 4}] := Tr[M.#]/4 & /@ Slist
```

Your example is then

```
coefflist[{{0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {-2, 0, 0, 0}}]
```

> {0, 2 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

To make this more readable, define names for the matrices:

```
Snames = ToExpression["S" <> StringJoin[#]] & /@ Tuples[{"x", "y", "z", "1"}, 2]
```

> {Sxx, Sxy, Sxz, Sx1, Syx, Syy, Syz, Sy1, Szx, Szy, Szz, Sz1, S1x, S1y, S1z, S11}

Your example matrix is identified as

```
Snames.coefflist[{{0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {-2, 0, 0, 0}}]
```

> 2 I Sxy

Let's check if this is correct:

```
2 I KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2]]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {-2, 0, 0, 0}}